# Better way to hide, change and show DIVs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I made this Javascript to hide, show and change some DIVs but I believe it's not really good code. Can you help me to make it better?

```
function colorM(n) {
    switch(n){
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("slideM1").style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC1").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("slideC2").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC3").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC4").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC5").style.display="none";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("slideM2").style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC1").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC2").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("slideC3").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC4").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC5").style.display="none";
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("slideM3").style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC1").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC2").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC3").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("slideC4").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC5").style.display="none";
            break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("slideM4").style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC1").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC2").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC3").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC4").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("slideC5").style.display="none";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("slideM5").style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC1").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC2").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC3").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC4").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC5").style.display="block";
            break;
        default: 
            document.getElementById("slideM1").style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM1").className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM2").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM3").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM4").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideM5").className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC1").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("slideC2").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC3").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC4").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("slideC5").style.display="none";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters: Instead of clearing the `className` of every div that you want to hide, assign a class name that already has the `background-color: 'silver'` and `display: none`. That alone saves you a lot of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the ID's instead of doing a switch. This should do the same as yours

```
function colorM(id){

    // if not a number
    if (!(!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n))) id =1;
    // default for numbers
    if (id > 5 || id < 1) id = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

        if (id == i){
            document.getElementById("slideM" + i).style.backgroundColor="#009CFF";
            document.getElementById("slideM" + i).className="show";
            document.getElementById("slideC" + i).style.display="block";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("slideM" + i).style.backgroundColor="silver";
            document.getElementById("slideM" + i).className="";
            document.getElementById("slideC" + i).style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: added a check if [id is numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/249710) AND id is within range

Comment: That's almost perfect but I need also default state. Which is explained in default case.

Comment: The default is the same as `1`? So make it in such a way that if you are trying to `default` it, (it is not any of the 5) it'll give `1` to the function

Comment: added a check in it!